# R, Filtering (subsetting) data with characters and assign names accordingly?

Tags: r, subset, assign

I have a data set `raw.data.2010` that needs several steps of subsetting with different animal species. I also need to name them accordingly after every filtering process. I wrote a simple code as below:

```
#Creating reproducible data######
site=rep(list("Q", "R", "S", "T"), each=500)
grid=sample(1:2, size=2000, replace=TRUE)
spp=rep(list("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), each=400)
fate=sample(1:5, size=20000, replace=TRUE)
sex=rep(list("M","F"), each=2000)
weight=sample(85:140, size=2000, replace=TRUE)

raw.data=as.data.frame(cbind(site, grid, spp, fate, sex, weight))

### main codes#####
spp=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
    for (i in spp){
        name=paste(i, "raw", sep=".", collapse="")
        filter=paste("select",i, sep="", collapse="")
        assign(filter, raw.data$spp==i)
        assign(name, raw.data[get(filter),])
    }
```

I checked the filters and they worked without problem. But the last line didn't work so all the subsetted data I called returned `NA`. What was wrong? Thank you.

**EDIT:** Hi, thank you all for your advice. I edited my codes so it's reproducible. Basically I would like to first filter my `raw.data` with `spp`. Then I can keep adding more filters to group them according to `site`, `grid`, `fate`...etc. I need to be able to access the filtered data individually so I can manipulate them for later use, ex. calculate weight and other measurements for different sex or age group. I want to be able to call `A.raw`, `A.Q.data` later.

Since I would like to analyze my data at different levels (e.g. population level, individual level, site/grid level), and be able to pool/split them according to my needs. That's the purpose of this code. Hope my explanation doesn't confuse you.

Comment: If you made a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your question / problem, we would find it easier to answer.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you would be better off doing something like `split(raw.data.2010,raw.data.2010$Spp)` -- but I strongly support @Andrie's suggestion of reproducible data, as well as a little bit more context: what are you going to do with the derived variables once you create them?

Comment: I edited my codes by adding a reproducible data.frame, and also added more explanation of my research purposes.

Comment: You should definitely check out the `plyr` package, which is exactly intended for this sort of task.

Comment: @ Ben Bolker, I tried 'split' and it was much faster. Plus, just use '$' to extract the species I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will probably save yourself a lot of work and grief in the long run if you move away from using global variables with `assign` and `get` and instead work with lists (and remember to subset using `[[` instead of `$`).

Comment: Oh, subsetting with [[ is faster than $? Sorry if it's common sense to all of you, I'm not a programmer at all, still learning.

Comment: It's not that "[[" is faster, it is safer and more flexible. It evaluates its argument which '$' does not. You wanted the filter object (terrible name by the way) to be evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems to be that you need to "get" the variable with the name stored in filter, rather than use filter itself.

This should work:

```
spp=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
for (i in spp){
    name=paste(i, "raw", sep=".", collapse="")
    filter=paste("select",i, sep="", collapse="")
    assign(filter, raw.data.2010$Spp==i)
    assign(name, raw.data.2010[get(filter),])
}
```

Comment: See @GregSnow's answer though too.  Using get and assign is, in general, not a good idea.  Work with lists instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is all mucked up. Here's a proper example and *never* ever use `as.data.frame(cbind(...))`

```
 site=rep(c("Q", "R", "S", "T"), each=500)
 grid=sample(1:2, size=2000, replace=TRUE)
 spp=rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), each=400)
 fate=sample(1:5, size=20000, replace=TRUE)
 sex=rep(c("M","F"), each=2000)
 weight=sample(85:140, size=2000, replace=TRUE)

 raw.data=data.frame(site=site, grid=grid, spp=spp, fate=fate, sex=sex, weight=weight)
 names(group.spp) <- paste(levels(raw.data$spp), "raw", sep=".")

#------------------------
 str(group.spp)
List of 5
 $ A.raw:'data.frame':  4000 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ site  : Factor w/ 4 levels "Q","R","S","T": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ grid  : int [1:4000] 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 ...
  ..$ spp   : Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ fate  : int [1:4000] 3 2 3 5 5 2 3 2 5 2 ...
  ..$ sex   : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ weight: int [1:4000] 136 93 115 100 97 128 120 124 97 120 ...
 $ B.raw:'data.frame':  4000 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ site  : Factor w/ 4 levels "Q","R","S","T": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ grid  : int [1:4000] 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ spp   : Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ fate  : int [1:4000] 5 5 2 4 3 4 2 3 4 5 ...
  ..$ sex   : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ weight: int [1:4000] 137 126 116 97 97 86 134 103 86 140 ...
 $ C.raw:'data.frame':  4000 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ site  : Factor w/ 4 levels "Q","R","S","T": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ grid  : int [1:4000] 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
  ..$ spp   : Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
  ..$ fate  : int [1:4000] 2 4 4 2 5 1 2 1 2 5 ...
  ..$ sex   : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ weight: int [1:4000] 132 85 96 87 91 94 94 122 116 87 ...
 $ D.raw:'data.frame':  4000 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ site  : Factor w/ 4 levels "Q","R","S","T": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
  ..$ grid  : int [1:4000] 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 ...
  ..$ spp   : Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
  ..$ fate  : int [1:4000] 2 4 1 4 2 4 1 5 1 4 ...
  ..$ sex   : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ weight: int [1:4000] 130 139 100 107 126 119 134 110 103 135 ...
 $ E.raw:'data.frame':  4000 obs. of  6 variables:
  ..$ site  : Factor w/ 4 levels "Q","R","S","T": 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
  ..$ grid  : int [1:4000] 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 ...
  ..$ spp   : Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
  ..$ fate  : int [1:4000] 5 5 4 5 5 3 1 4 4 3 ...
  ..$ sex   : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..$ weight: int [1:4000] 88 96 99 101 119 94 97 132 137 115 ...
```